# Request permission

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I implemented speech recognition feature in Xamarin iOS app. It requires microphone and speech permission and so I described permission in info.plist

When launch app it displays dialog to ask speech permission.
But if disable speech permission, it doesn't ask microphone permission, and also I can't see microphone permission in Settings.(only can see speech permission)

What I want is that I want to show microphone permission dialog even disabling speech permission.

In a work I want to show two all permission dialogs.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Could you attach a copy of your `info.plist`?

Comment: @StefanoBuora I just added screen

Comment: I think it's due to the priority of  permission ,and also  there are some relationships between speech permission and microphone, once you disable one, another will be disabled either.  But if you disable speech permission, it will not effect another uncorrelated permission ,for example Camera ,Bluetooth ,Location  and so on.

Comment: @ColeXia, I already changed priority of permission. But same result.
Is there any way to ask permission manually ?